# Binding radio button content to a dataset

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `listView`. What i need is to display a list of radio buttons on this list. For each distinct `Name` in `exercises` (which is basically a collection of entries from a database table), there should be a radio button with its content being `Name`.

```
private void GetChartData()
{ 
    ExercicesList.ItemsSource = exercises.Select(n => n.Name).Distinct();  
}
```

So far it displays the radio buttons, however not their content.

```
<ListView Name="ExercicesList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 100 0 0">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <Grid>
                     <RadioButton Name="ExerciceCheck" GroupName="onlyOne" Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="False" Checked="ExerciceCheck_Checked"></RadioButton>
                  </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: not sure yet, but shouldnt you bind the content to the partens context: hence to that Binding needs a source. you might try this:  Content="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ExercicesList.ItemsSource = exercises.Select(n => n.Name).Distinct();
```

this code extract only the `Name` (`IEnumerable<string>`), not the `exercise` object (`IEnumerable<exercise>`). the `RadioButton.Content` binding try access a Name property, And there is not exsist in `string`. You can do a Binding to element itself - without a property:

```
Content="{Binding}"
```

it work, but you lose access to other properties later in the logic.

instead, Leave the XAML as it is, just write this way when putting the list:

```
ExercicesList.ItemsSource = exercises.GroupBy(n => n.Name).Select(g => g.First());
```

Because there is no `DistinctBy` in linq, use GropyBy & Select first from each group, for the same effect.